# How to Make Sure a Space that is filled is not taken up again in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

This is my first time on this website. I am VERY new to java and coding in general so I will most likely need in depth explanations. I am writing a program that takes 12 students and places them in seats in a 5 rows, 6 columns array classroom. I have to prevent out of bounds exceptions and prevent a student from taking a seat that has already been filled. **I need help with making sure a student doesn't take a seat that has already been filled. I do not know how to do this.** Here is my code so far:

```
public class Classroom
{
public static void printArray(char[][] array)
{

    for(int row=0;row<5;++row)
    {
        System.out.print("| "); 
        for(int col =0;col<6;++col)
            System.out.print(array[row][col] + "| "); 
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int col =0;col<6;++col)
        System.out.print("---");
    System.out.println(); 
}

public static void main()
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    char[][] array = new char[5][6];
    for(int i =0;i<5;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<6;++j)
            array[i][j] = ' '; 

    printArray(array); 
    for(int x =1;x<14;++x)
    {


        System.out.print("Choose column (1-6) for a student: "); 
        int column = reader.nextInt(); 
        System.out.print("Choose row (1-5) for a student: "); 
        int row = reader.nextInt(); 


        if(column <1 || column>6 || row<1 || row>5)
        {
            System.out.println(); 
            System.out.println("Column should be from 1 to 6. Row should be from 1 to 5.");

            System.out.println("The program will restart from student 1."); 
            System.out.println(); 

            x=1;
            for(int i =0;i<5;++i)
                for(int j=0;j<6;++j)
                    array[i][j] = ' '; 

            continue;
        }


        for(int i =0;i<5;++i)
            for(int j=0;j<6;++j)

                array[row-1][column-1] = 'S';
        printArray(array);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and change your title to describe problem you are facing. Remember that purpose of Stack Overflow is to be searchable repository of programming questions and answers so make this title specific and related to problem you are facing. Actually beside title change, you should also describe problem you are facing in main body of your post.

Comment: This doesn't describe the problem you are facing. Please specify the **exact** issue you are having with solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (array[row-1][column-1] == 'S') {
            System.out.println("This seat is taken! Please choose another.");
            continue;
        }
```

This will print to the console when they try to enter a seat that is already taken. You just needed to check if the current row/column contains a person, or in your case, value 'S'

You should be adding this right after the row is read from the scanner to prevent it from executing the rest of your code.